# Elasticsearch take into account likes when doing significant_terms aggregation with Function score

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using terms aggregation to figure out what the common tags are this week from all blogposts.

```
  body: {
    query: {
      bool: {
        filter: { 
          "range": {
            "created": {
              gte: new Date().getWeek(new Date().getWeek() - 1)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "tags": {
        "terms": { "field": "tags" },
      }
    }
  }
```

However, instead of scoring based on the most used tags I would like to bias it for tags on posts that have a lot of likes based on the field "likes" of int type.

Can someone show me how to combine function scores with aggregations please? Thanks.

Comment: I dont think I can solve this, but just wanted to try . Please can you add what is the output you're getting V/S what is your expected output?

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat Just looking for a list of tags, it's sorted atm by the number of items in each bucket rather than any properties on those items.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation again I'm fairly confident this is actually not possible using elasticsearch and it needs a different solution.

```
Available parameters in the script are

_subset_freq

Number of documents the term appears in the subset.

_superset_freq

Number of documents the term appears in the superset.

_subset_size

Number of documents in the subset.

_superset_size

Number of documents in the superset.
```

You cannot access docs while doing significant terms aggregation scripting.

Comment: @Johnny, maybe, not sure how to do that though. Can you help?

Comment: I haven't fully understood what you mean, but I think it's ok to do it in groups.